# Where i need to put validation code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form with a number of fields.

Some of them are userId, userFirstName, userLastName.

When user inputs incorrect userId value then near userId field page must show error message and add this error into validationSummary(this is standart behavior for asp.net mvc unobtrusive validation). If userId is correct then page must remove errors and autopopulate userFirstName and userLastName(This is not standart behavior)

How can i implement this?

Here is what come to my mind:

1. Remote validation attribute

   It has a bad customization in my case. That's why i decide to don't use it.
2. Add special method for jquery validation plugin ( for example

   jQuery.validator.addMethod("userIdValidation", function(value, element) {
     //some logic
     return something;
   }, "Please specify the correct userId"); )

and put there logic for validation and for autopopulate other fields.
In this case i mix validation and other stuff.

3 . Add special method for jquery validation plugin ONLY for validation and add special handler for input change event for autopopulate.

In this case i need to send TWO ajax requests to server for one thing. And ofcourse it is not good too. So what is the right way? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a partial view to display the userFirstName and userLastName?

You can fire an AJAX request that sends the userId, and then returns a partial view of the name fields. Within the controller being called, you can validate the incoming userId, and then grab the name details in one query. If thevalidation fails, you can return the partial view with empty fields.